# Split a data file into files for each time step

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-limit-exceeded, file

I have written a simple code to extract different time steps from a big text file. It works for small text files, but not for bigger text files as input.

```
n=0
y=[]
with open ("DEPTH.dat", "r") as input:
    for x in input:
        x = x.strip()
        if x.startswith('SCALAR'):
            n += 1
        with open("TS_"+ str(n) + ".dat", "a") as subfile:
                subfile.write("{0}\n".format(x))
```

The input file is like the following:

```
SCALAR
ND   5
ST  0
TS        10.00
    0.0022
    0.0022
    0.0022
    0.0020
    0.4881
SCALAR
ND   5
ST  0
TS        100.00
    0.1
    0.2
    0.12
    0.32
    0.15
SCALAR
ND   5
ST  0
TS        200.00
    0.34
    0.25
    1.1
    1.0020
    1.4381
```

In this example file, the number of nodes `ND=5` , so it works very well. But when I have 1,000,000 nodes, it does not work. It does not deliver any result even after 20 days. So I know I have to write the program as a function and return the result and not to upload the whole data into memory. I have no I idea  how to do that.

Comment: While there could be more efficient solutions, I'd recommend [`csplit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/csplit.1.html) utility.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that tou are trying to split one large file into smaller files with a sequential filename?

Comment: I want to be able to split it in any part of the Depth.dat file. which means I have sometimes 50 GB Depth.dat file and I need time steps 25 to 28 and 501 to 505 when the total numebr of time steps is 1000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### IO operations

Your code for each line of "DEPTH.dat" first open file in append mode, next write one line and finally close file. You may reduce open() and close() calls only to lines when 'SCALAR' line appears.

```
def split_less_io_operations(src_filename):
    idx = 1
    with open(src_filename, 'r') as inp:
        outfile = open("TS_before_first_SCALAR.dat", 'w')
        for line in inp:
            if line.startswith('SCALAR'):
                outfile.close()
                outfile = open("TS_{}.dat".format(idx), 'w')
                idx += 1
            outfile.write(line)
        outfile.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    split_less_io_operations('DEPTH.dat')
```